# Azure Database list in a database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

The requirement is simple the execute somewhat troublesome.

I have Azure SQL Database called "MyDB". I want to populate a table in MyDB with DB_ID and DatabaseName with all of the database on the same server.

Now If I use  "SELECT name, database_id FROM sys.databases" using master I can get the information I require but I cannot seem to fine a method to do a cross db insert into from master to MyDB. This is a Azure SQL Database not a VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do cross database queries from within an Azure SQL Database at this time. So, in order to do what you want, you'd be better off doing it externally using something like Powershell to automate the process.

Comment: Depending on the requirements, I suppose you could also have two separate database connections - one for MyDB and one for Master within the same app. You could read from the Master connection and write to the MyDB tables from the MyDB connection.

Comment: I am trying to create Dynamic Link server connections from a Azure VM so every time someone create or drops a Azure DB a trigger will fire and update the table, I can use a Solid Link Server connection from Azure to look at that table, Issues are I cannot create a Link Server to Master, I can link to MyDB but I cannot populate MyBb from master.

Comment: Yeah, @RobReagan, no reason why that wouldn't work too.

Comment: @icecurtain I wouldn't suggest trying that process through T-SQL then. Instead I would look into using Powershell and Azure Automation. I haven't built something like this so I don't have a specific model for you. I'd start here to explore the concepts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings